# How to dynamically update jquery datatable using js array as data source

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

How to dynamically update jquery datatable using js array as data source.
When user click the update button a new js array should be added current data source and it should reflect on jquery datatable.

```
<html>
    <head>       
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="demo"></div>
        <button id="update">Update</button>  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var dataSet = [
        ['Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','4','X'],
        ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C'],
        ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.5','Win 95+','5.5','A'],    
    ];

    var ctr = 0;
    $("#update").click(function() {        
        ctr++;
        dataSet.push([ctr,ctr,ctr,ctr,ctr]);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(dataSet));
    });

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo').html( '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>' );
     $('#example').dataTable( {
        "data": dataSet,
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Engine" },
            { "title": "Browser" },
            { "title": "Platform" },
            { "title": "Version", "class": "center" },
            { "title": "Grade", "class": "center" }
        ]
    });   
});

    </script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of manipulating the initial data array, I recommend using the DataTables API methods like `row.add()` and `draw()` to update the data. If you need the data after the initialisation, you can access it with the `data()` method.

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLzw8tu5/) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Persist the data table in a global js variable- `dataTable`. Once you `dataSet` changes, just destroy `dataTable` and initialize it again.

```
if(dataTable != null)
    dataTable.destroy();

dataTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "data": dataSet,
    "columns": [
        { "title": "Engine" },
        { "title": "Browser" },
        { "title": "Platform" },
        { "title": "Version", "class": "center" },
        { "title": "Grade", "class": "center" }
    ]
    });
```

Comment: There is no `destroy()` method if table is initialized with `dataTable()`, in this case it should be `api().destroy()`.